# .mdb file and MinGX, MinGY, MaxGx, MaxGY parameters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, ms-access

I have .mdb file ( Microsoft Access file ) which appears to be a shapefile index ( snapshot as attached ) and i need to get longitude and latitude from this so that file can be fed to Tableau or PowerBI for visualization purpose.

[image]

Comment: You can add it to ArcMap if it has geometries. Then use tool Add Geometry Attributes to calculate centroids or whatever you are asking.

Comment: Have you looked inside your .mdb with ArcCatalog? It's probably a personal geodatabase, in which case I wouldn't be poking around too much in the system tables (which table is this?), if only tables can bee seen then it's not a personal geodatabase in which case you need to find out what coordinate system the numbers are in; the X values are far too large for UTM and there's no decimals which makes me think those numbers may not be coordinates at all.

Answer (score 1):

These are probably easting/northing values so it depends on where the data is on the globe. To get Longitude Latitude you need to transform it and for that, you need to find out the projection system. You can use QGIS with OpenLayers plugin to help in locating the points in the basemap.

Answer (score 1):

You have to project them to latlon system. QGIS can project to latlon system.

Answer (score 0):

Find the `IdxGridSize` and `IdxOriginX`/`IdxOriginY` values in `GDB_GeomColumns` for your table first.

Then, multiply the `MinGX`/`MinGY`/`MaxGX`/`MaxGY` values with the grid size and add the origin values. You'll end up with the min/max coordinates in the projected system. You can convert the coordinates into lat/lon values using Proj4.js or some other tool.